# Error: Pixel type not supported in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD13A1').select('NDVI');

// Define reference conditions from the first 10 years of data.
var reference = collection.filterDate('2001-01-01', '2010-12-31')
  // Sort chronologically in descending order.
  .sort('system:time_start', false);

// Compute the mean of the first 10 years.
var mean = reference.mean();

// Compute anomalies by subtracting the 2001-2010 mean from each image in a
// collection of 2011-2014 images. Copy the date metadata over to the
// computed anomaly images in the new collection.

var series = collection.filterDate('2011-01-01', '2014-12-31').map(function(image) {return image.subtract(mean).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// Display cumulative anomalies.
Map.setCenter(84, 27, 5);
Map.addLayer(series.sum().clip(Da),
    {min: -60000, max: 60000, palette: ['FF0000', '000000', '00FF00']}, 'NDVI anomaly');

// Get the timestamp from the most recent image in the reference collection.
var time0 = reference.first().get('system:time_start');

// Use imageCollection.iterate() to make a collection of cumulative anomaly over time.
// The initial value for iterate() is a list of anomaly images already processed.
// The first anomaly image in the list is just 0, with the time0 timestamp.
var first = ee.List([
  // Rename the first band 'NDVI'.
  ee.Image(0).set('system:time_start', time0).select([0], ['NDVI'])
]);

// This is a function to pass to Iterate().
// As anomaly images are computed, add them to the list.
var accumulate = function(image, list) {
  // Get the latest cumulative anomaly image from the end of the list with
  // get(-1).  Since the type of the list argument to the function is unknown,
  // it needs to be cast to a List.  Since the return type of get() is unknown,
  // cast it to Image.
  var previous = ee.Image(ee.List(list).get(-1));
  // Add the current anomaly to make a new cumulative anomaly image.
  var added = image.add(previous)
    // Propagate metadata to the new image.
    .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start')).float();
  // Return the list with the cumulative anomaly inserted.
  return ee.List(list).add(added);
};

// };
// Create an ImageCollection of cumulative anomaly images by iterating.
// Since the return type of iterate is unknown, it needs to be cast to a List.


var cumulative = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(series.iterate(accumulate, first)));

print (cumulative);

var counter = 0;

// loop through the year
for (var y = 2011; y < 2015 ; y++) {
  // loop through the months
  for (var m = 1; m < 12 ; m++) {
  
  // get the image
  var img = ee.Image(cumulative.toList(1, counter).get(0));
 
  // store the image
  Export.image.toDrive({
       image: img,
       description: y.toString() + m.toString(),
       scale: 1000,
    region: Da
 });
}}
```

I am getting this error while running this code `Error: Pixel type not supported: Type<MaskOnly>. Convert the image to a floating point type or a smaller integer type, for example, using ee.Image.toDouble().` I tried to convert image to float but still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earth Engine is getting confused when it tries to export that first image and finds that it's constant and all zeros. The error can be fixed by casting the `first` image with `.float()`.

```
var first = ee.List([
  // Rename the first band 'NDVI'.
  ee.Image(0).set('system:time_start', time0).select([0], ['NDVI']).float()
]);
```

In fact, take a close look at the export loop.  I don't think it's doing what you want.  Don't export an image of all zeros.  Don't convert cumulative to an `ImageCollection` and back to a list again.  (Avoid converting to a list in general as described [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/best_practices#avoid-converting-to-list-unnecessarily)). The `counter` variable is not updated. (Should it be?)